# angularjs directive with dynamic templates and string interpolation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The idea is to replace the directive element with the dynamic template which refers to interpolated strings.

If I use element.html() in my directive then the strings are interpolated fine but this leaves the original custom directive html element.

If I use element.replaceWith() then strings are not interpolated. I guess it has related to scope but can't figure out what's wrong.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HyBP9d?p=preview

### UPDATE

Found the solution. Using `element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));` works.

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HyBP9d?p=preview

Comment: You can remove `replace: true` and `transclude: true` from your directive.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what objective is regarding `replaceWIth`. The problem is likely that when you replace an elememnt, you replace all events and data bound to it. This would include the angular scope for the element.

For demo provided could do it like this:

```
app.directive('status', function($compile) {       

        var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.contents().wrap('<h'+attrs.value+'>')
        };

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template:'<div>{{value}}</div>',
            transclude: true,
            link: linker,
            scope: {
                value: '='
            }
        };
    });
```

DEMO:http://plnkr.co/edit/QDxIwE?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. For demo that could work. But in my real use case dynamic template could totally be different from other which depends on incoming 'value'.